# Activity with fragments. Soft keyboard covers input

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Activity with LinearLayout and two fragments:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment
    android:name="com.xmstr.myshoplist.ListZoneFragment"
    android:id="@+id/list_zone_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/list_zone" />
<fragment
    android:name="com.xmstr.myshoplist.NewItemZoneFragment"
    android:id="@+id/new_item_zone_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    tools:layout="@layout/newitem_zone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

First fragment contains only ListView
Second fragment is "Add new item zone":
EditText and "Add button"

**PROBLEM:**
When soft keyboard appears, it covers EditText input.
Tried manifest features such as: ajustResize, ajustPan. They didnt help. Keyboard still covers EditText or i cant see actionbar of my app

**WHAT I WANT:**
First fragment must be static and not resizeble in all situatons.
Can second fragment stick to the top border of soft keyboard (when it appears) and move up with it?

How to handle this? Or problem is how i using layout_weight in my xml?